# Proof of the law of reflection without calculus

Tags: trigonometry, physics

I am working on some optimization problems, and I am aware of the method of proving that the "*angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection*" using Fermat's principle and calculus.

However, my textbook suggests that there is a simple way to prove this without calculus, but I'm a little unsure about how to do this. I would appreciate any advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Perhaps you can turn to the Huygens principle.

Comment: Hint: Say the mirror is a horizontal line $\ell$, and the light wants to get from $A$ to $B$ as fast as possible, being reflected at $X$. **Reflect** $B$ in $\ell$, getting the point $B'$. The shortest path $AX+XB$ occurs when $X$ is the point where $AB'$ meets $\ell$.

Comment: Proof seems like such a strange thing for a physical phenomena. This law of reflection is a consequence of Fermat's principle of least time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are two points on the same side of the mirror.  A ray of light from $A$ reflects off the mirror and goes to $B$. If I understand correctly, what is to be proved is this: among all paths going from $A$ to the mirror and then to $B$, the shortest one is the one for which the two angles are equal.

A way to prove that is to consider the ray of light going from $A$ straight through the mirror to the location of the reflection of $B$.  The shortest path is a straight line.  Think about what that implies about the various angles.